# Low loss method of connecting two dissimilar battery voltages together without a diode?

Tags: diodes, powermosfet

TLDR; Is there a simple circuit which delivers a diode's robust reverse-voltage behavior, only with an order of magnitude less heat generation?

---

I have two lithium batteries with different chemistries and I would like to connect them together in parallel. Let's call them *B_hv* and *B_lv*.

Due to the difference in chemistry, at fully-charged voltage *B_hv* is several volts higher than *B_lv*, i.e. ~70V vs ~50V. Once under load, *B_hv* sags enough that it reaches the same voltage as *B_lv*, and both discharge into the load. However, before this point *B_hv* cannot be allowed to discharge into the *B_lv*.

An easy way to do this is to put a diode between *B_lv*'s positive terminal and the connection point. This works fine, but at the cost of significant energy loss. (The best high-power diodes have a voltage drop around 0.4V.)

I'd like to use a MOSFET instead, as they are cheaper and more efficient for the nominal current load (>200A). There's a clever circuit to use a [P-FET as a reverse protection diode](https://hackaday.com/2011/12/06/reverse-voltage-protection-with-a-p-fet/), but this takes advantage of the large difference between a properly-connected battery and a reversely-connected battery. In this case, though, the difference between voltage is small, in the range of 0-20V.

It would be straightforward to use a uC to measure the voltage across the FET and turn the FET off if the output were higher than the input. However, this adds significant complexity both in firmware and in the circuit (e.g. the uC will need its own low-voltage power supply).

Furthermore, the uC would be constantly consuming electricity, which might discharge the battery if left unattended for long enough. And a uC can fail, due to a bug or EM noise.

A diode is admirable in that it is simple and passively does the right thing. Short of mechanical failure, it will be robust and reliable for decades. It also doesn't require a connection to ground, it works via the voltage differential between the input and output, keeping it extremely safe.

Is there a way to have similar behavior to the diode, only instead with a FET like in the reverse voltage protection circuit?

Comment: 0.4 / 50V is not significant  But power FETs can become ideal diodes, you ought to have low V cutoff and a BMS

Comment: Frankly, at the risk of sounding offensive, that's not for you to decide. 0.4V at 200A is a serious amount of heat which I do not want to have to deal with. Likewise, a BMS is a poor choice in this system, as it adds significant complexity, cost, and points of failure.

Comment: What are the safe voltages for UV on 70V bank ? after <50V is reached.  normally 3V/cell depending on ESR and discharge rate.   A crossover switch can be designed to  prevent this. with <=1mohm RdsOn and hysteresis on the switch.   never underestimate the value of good specs, including load reactance. Make it list like a datasheet.

Comment: How much power dissipaiton is too much power? At 200A, even a FET with 1mOhm Rds(on) would be 40W dissipation (2mOhm would be the same 80W as your diode). You'd need 125uOhm would be 5W.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, let's be careful about assumptions. Safe voltage is a function of chemistry, and in this case is 2V/cell, not 3V. We're more than okay at the 50V threshold. A cross-over switch is inapplicable, as my understanding is it would disconnect B_hv from the circuit, which would defeat the purpose of two batteries. I agree with the analysis of the Rds(on): at peak current it would take several parallel MOSFETs to achieve better performance than a diode. However, at half-current the situation improves significantly as the I2R losses decrease quadratically, but VI decreases linearly.

Comment: You can build an ideal diode oring circuit using NMOS transistors though it's a bit more tricky, those will give better power handling over PMOs.

Comment: Unless you have a real design spec with all factors that can screw things up, my 1st comment using an ideal FET diode is all I will contribute, paralleling 2V lithium ? strings ?  under high discharge rates can circulate under certain transient condition

Comment: We have a real design spec and a real system, thanks. The question elicited a great answer, so I think we're okay on that front.

Comment: Mmmm, gotta love rude downvoters. If you're going to downvote, please explain why. The answer to the question was not obvious for non-EE peeps, and would obviously help anyone who had a similar situation. The concept of using the elegant ideal diode controller described in @jp314's answer was exactly what was necessary, and was unlikely to be found by simply doing a trade-space review of low forward-voltage diodes. Nor is it reflexively obvious to use a MOSFET *backwards*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an 'Ideal Diode Controller'. Basically this is a comparator (comparing the V across a FET (which is acting as a switch), and turning on the FET if necessary.

Sometimes these are slow, so a pulse of reverse current can flow if the other V is connected suddenly.

You can find these ICs on the web.

Comment: Thanks! TIL "ideal diode" is a real thing, and something more than something we find in the "ideal circuit schematic"

Comment: I wired up the ideal diode controller today and it worked exactly what I needed. Thanks again for the excellent advice.